# Unit Test Debugging with Selenium for MVC applicaiton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, selenium

When trying to debug a unit test, I am able to hit a breakpoint in the test code itself.  However, any breakpoints I have set within my MVC application (ie: controller code) are not getting hit.  As soon as the test is running, the breakpoints in the MVC application say No symbols loaded.  It's not clear to me how Selenium loads the web application.  I have a reference to the MVC project in my test code, but it makes no difference. It is clear the assembly is not loaded (as viewed in the Modules window).  How can I hit breakpoints outside of the actual unit test project?  Simple example, each test performs a login.  I add a breakpoint to the validation, and it never gets hit.

Comment: That is because selenium open the page in another process

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know how I can determine where it is loading the MVC application from?  When I run the app, I don't get the errror that I am getting from the unit test, so I am sure it is picking up a stale version.  I don't have to have a reference to my MVC application in my test project, so that is a clue.

Comment: Try this steps.....run the app project and let it running....then run the test project

Comment: Excellent.  That did it, thanks so much!

Comment: Just for clarity purposes....maybe your test was failing because the mvc project was not running xD....it happened to me once so no problem :)